# Could web crawlers reach my sandbox force.com sites?

Tags: force.com-sites, org, web

How about sites on a dev org or partner edition orgs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a web crawler could reach them. If someone can access the Force.com site by typing the URL into the address bar of their browser then a web crawler (computer program) could access it as well.

You can set a [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) file to specify what you want or don't want indexed and all web crawlers that are written to honor robots.txt directives will follow it.  However, there is nothing technically stopping a computer program from accessing your site if it is written to do so.

You can view the robots.txt file for your Force.com Site at http://thedomain.com/sitename/robots.txt (e.g., http://abc-developer-edition.na.15.force.com/testsite/robots.txt.  If you don't set up a robots.txt file on your Force.com Site in a dev org you get the default. The default is to disallow everything:

```
#
# robots.txt for sfdc appservers.
#
# For use by salesforce.com
#
User-agent: *    # applies to all robots
Disallow: /      # disallow indexing of all pages
```

The Salesforce help has information about setting up a robots.txt file for your Force.com Site.  From [the help page](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=sites_creating_and_editing_sites.htm&siteLang=en_US):

> A file that determines which parts of your public site Web spiders and
>   other Web robots can access. Web robots are often used by search
>   engines to categorize and archive websites. HTML tags are not allowed,
>   as they are not compatible with robots.txt spiders. For Visualforce
>   pages, add `contentType="text/plain"` to the `<apex:page>` tag.
>
> Example disallowing all robots from indexing all pages:
>
> ```
> <apex:page contentType="text/plain">
>     User-agent: *  # Applies to all robots
>     Disallow: /    # Disallow indexing of all pages
> </apex:page>
> ```
>
> Example allowing all robots to index all pages:
>
> ```
> <apex:page contentType="text/plain">
>     User-agent: *  # Applies to all robots
>     Disallow:      # Allow indexing of all pages
> </apex:page>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  If you've got requirements to not have that happen, you can also ip-restrict the site to only allow certain ranges to view the site.